# How to fix deep linking in iOS when the application has not installed in the device?

Tags: android, ios, codeigniter, deep-linking

I'm working with deep linking features for android and iOS, my back end is in CI. The deep linking is working for both Android and iOS when the application is installed. But if the application has not been installed then I face the problem.

I have tried it this way:
When any user clicks on the link then first it will redirect to the browser, after that from my back end code I am checking that the client device type. If the device is Android then I am redirecting it to Android application, if the device is iOS then it redirect to iOS application.
But when the application hasn't been installed, it stops working.

For Android I have put the following code:

```
header("Location: my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here")
```

For iOS have added the application scheme just before the URL.

I think I have described all my scenarios. Please guide me how it should be redirected to the app store or the specific page when the application is not installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically what happens is that you try to deep link using the URI scheme provided above (`my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here`) and it fails since the app is not installed. In that case you cannot catch the failure and redirect the user elsewhere.

You can set your BE to return something similar to this:

```
window.location.href = "my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here";
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = ...store_link_for_your_app..;
}, 1000);
```

That way, if deep link fails, after 1s you'll get a redirect.

Important notes:

- Not all browsers support deep link via URI Schemes. In Chrome for example this will fail. here you'll have to use Intents, see https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents
- In iOS 9+, safari browser will block usage of URI schemes if the app is not installed - you'll get an error on screen about your URL validity. Here you'll need to implement Universal Links, see https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/

Comment: I forgot to thank you Man. Sorry for that. 
It is working for me. Thank you again.

Comment: Sure, no problem! Happy to hear that :-)

Comment: Does not work on safari, it shows the appstore URL.

Answer (score 8):

Hope help anyone:

```
var deeplinkUrl = `yourscheme://myurl?param1=x&param2=y`;
//variable will check app installed or not
var change = false;
setTimeout(() => {
  if (!change) {
    var redirectUrl = "your store url";
    window.location = redirectUrl;
  }
}, 3000);
window.location = deeplinkUrl;
//handle event to check app installed or not
window.onblur = function () {
    change = true;
};
window.onfocus = function(){
    change = false;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: if not installed yet => will show an error (onblur event)=> click in error alert it will invoke onfocus event again (change = false) => continue go to store.
if installed app => will show an confirm alert (mean : do u want open application) (onblur event invoked ) but not run onfocus again if u click open application(because leave web application)

Comment: Hey this solution is working but there is one issue on Safari browser it shows the alert dialog which says the link can not be opened because of an invalid protocol is there any way to avoid this dialog